# How to know the row written when using writerow()?

Tags: python, csv

```
writer.writerow(["Foo", "Bar"])
```

How to know the row number written when using writerow?
I've already tried to get the return but it's "None" type and the documentation seems to not talk about something like that.

Comment: You'll have to keep a count yourself of the number of times you've called  `writerow()`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code to help you with the row number using the enumerate function in Python 3.5.2:

```
import csv
myDataList = ["Foo", "Bar"]
with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
    for i, row in enumerate(myDataList):
        data = [i, row]
        w.writerow(data)
```